# How to Merge selected Dynamic table cells

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a Dynamic table.Table cells are generating Dynamically.How can i merge selected table cells?

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>head1</th>
<th>head2</th>
<th>head3</th>
<th>head4</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please elaborate on which condition you want to merge the cells

Comment: Weird, a vote so soon for a question like this?

Comment: May be duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22497969/how-can-i-merge-selected-table-cells-using-jquery

Comment: Need to merge selected column cells(combined to single)

Comment: Which table cells are selected? How are they selected? Please ma a jsFiddle and elaborate on the many possibilities.

Comment: using mouse selected table cells

Comment: If you need us to help you, you need to be more specific.  Eg. When you have the word Title inside the cell you need yo make it colspan='2'. Something like that

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/V3YUe/1/)**</kbd>

As answered here [how can I merge selected table cells using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22497969/how-can-i-merge-selected-table-cells-using-jquery)

jquery

```
 $("document").ready(function () {
     $("table").delegate("td", "click", function () {
         var colSp = prompt("Number of cells to span");
         $(this).attr("colspan", colSp);

         var ptr = $(this).parent().children();
         for (var i = 1; i < colSp; i++) {
             ptr[ptr.length - i].parentNode.removeChild(ptr[ptr.length - i]);
         }
     });
 });
```

css

```
table td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```